One-liner split and map within list comprehension
I have this bit for parsing some output from stdout:
out_lines = res.stdout.split("\n")
out_lines = [e.split() for e in out_lines]
out_vals = [{"date":e[0],
             "time":e[1],
             "size":e[2],
             "name":e[3]} for e in out_lines if e]

Is there an idiomatic way to merge the second and third lines here so that the splitting and mapping happen within the same line, without redundant calls to e.split()?

You might be able to do it using the walrus operator to hold the results of e.split(), but it won't be pretty.

I would go another way and add a helper function (like my_obj_from_line) do do the split and construct the new object.

@trincot's answer works but can avoid a post-processing filter by mapping the lines to str.split so that the filtering can be done with the if clause of the comprehension instead:
out_vals = [
    dict(zip(("date", "time", "size", "name"), e))
    for e in map(str.split, res.stdout.split("\n")) if e
]


You could use zip to pair the keys with the words and then feed that to the dict constructor.
Then if split() would result in an empty list, you'd get empty objects which you can filter out later:
out_vals = list(filter(None, (
    dict(zip(("date", "time", "size", "name"), line.split()))
    for line in res.stdout.split("\n")
)))


You can use:
[{"date": e[0], "time": e[1], "size": e[2], "name": e[3]} for e in (line.split() for line in sample_stdout.split("\n")) if e]


A little bit of a modification of trincot's approach: breaking out the line.split() by binding the name data to a singleton tuple, and using if line.strip() to address empty lines, rather than using filter afterwards.
[
  dict(zip(("date", "time", "size", "name"), data))
  for line in text.splitlines()
  if line.strip()
  for data in (line.split(),)
]

